# Replace button by a component/circuit in 555 diagram

Tags: circuit-design, 555, button, replacement

I need your help im crazy with this, i already tried many ways to do it, i need to replace the push button in this circuit by a component or circuit to be activated for a signal of 5 v such as a microcontroller one, please help me, could you draw a diagram for me with this.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I would consider finding a different circuit that does the same thing but where one side of the button is connected to ground. Then use an NPN transistor.

Comment: If you are using a microcontroller to drive this why are you using a 555?

Comment: i haven't found a circuit with this trigger function and the button connected directly to ground, and im not using a microcontroller im using a 5v pulse from a battery, could you help me with a diagram?

Answer (score 2):

It wouldn't be a great design, but if you were an electronics beginner and just wanted a simple substitution, you could use a relay instead of the button.

edit: added schematic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNVhUC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Two relays, a 555 and a half-dozen passives does seem like overkill to turn a small LED on and off using a microcontroller.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick Yeah, needs another 555 as a buffer between the relay and the microcontroller

Comment: I'm so tempted to recommend a 741.

Comment: could you bring me a circuit to help me?

Comment: @Jamie I added a circuit diagram

Comment: is there another way using transistors instead of a relay?

Comment: @Jaime Almost certainly yes, but you haven't given enough information for us to understand what you want. What do you want this circuit to do?